# extending class function like codeigniter

Tags: php

If you use codeigniter (maybe other framework too) , you can use something like this

```
$this->db->query()->row();
```

Now, i want to create something like that . For now , i have this simple class

```
class Users
{
    function getUser(){

    }
}
```

so, when i'm trying my class above i can use this

```
<?php
require 'Users.php';
$users= new Users();
$users->getUser();
```

but, what i want is. I can add `order` in my function. So `maybe` i can create like this

```
<?php
require 'Users.php';
$users= new Users();
$users->getUser()->orderby("fullname","asc");
```

how can i achieve that ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is called method chaining. For it to work, each method returns an object, which may be the same object.

Example:

```
class Users
{
    function getUser(){
        return new User();
    }
}
```

If you use:

```
<?php
require 'Users.php';
$users= new Users();
$users->getUser()->orderby("fullname","asc");
```

`getUser` will be called on `Users` and `orderby` will be called on `User`.